# Xamarin iOS - multiple text colors in a label in listview

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hi I have a requirement to show a label with multiple colors.
Something like this:

[image]

For android I use TextType = HTML and use font color to achieve this.

But ios doesn't support text type html with custom font.
Is there any other way to do it in ios?

Answer (score 2):

you can use Label FormattedText

View Model file

```
private string firstText{ get; set; } = "First";
public string FirstText
{
   get { return firstText; }
   set
   {
      firstText = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
 }

private string secondText{ get; set; } = "Second";
public string SecondText
{
   get { return secondText}
   set
   {
      secondText = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
 }
private string thirdText{ get; set; } = "Third";
public string ThirdText
{
   get { return thirdText}
   set
   {
      thirdText = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
 }
```

.xaml file

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label.FormattedText>
         <FormattedString>
                 <FormattedString.Spans>
                      <Span Text="{Binding FirstText}" TextColor="Red" />
                      <Span Text="{Binding SecondText}" TextColor="Blue" />
                      <Span Text="{Binding ThirdText}" TextColor="Aqua" />

                  </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: The problem is the string is not static. Its a bound property:

    
<Label Text = "{Binding DisplayText}">

I have 3 properties. 
1. Display text
2. GreenColorIndex
3. OrangeColorIndex

@Ryan Mortal: Can we make ur code as dynamic?

Comment: @GurmeetKhalsa , you can split your Text into 3 Bindable string and bind it into the Span, I'll update my answer... Can i see some of your code?